# Differen UINavigationbars Xcode

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am currently learning Xcode and I noticed that there are two different navigation bars: 1. Added automatically when working with the `Navigation Controller` and 2. the one I can add "manually" as an object.

The one I can add manually (Image 2) doesn't go to the top of the screen compared to the auto one  (Image 1), how can I change this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: @YuviGr what do you mean by that. I am using the Storyboard, yes

Comment: are you setting the autolayout constraints of the objects?

Comment: @YuviGr Yes I am using the auto function for adding constraints

Comment: Hi, sorry but i need more detail on how you create, maybe add an image of your storyboard? or code you have that is relevant

Comment: @YuviGr the image you see at the top is generated by the Navigation controller in a table view controller. The one at the bottom is simple a navigation bar from the object library in the Storyboard dragged into a normal view. That's basically it

Comment: have you tried adding a UIView at the top of your NavigationBar? you can set it to have 20 pt height and change the color to match the navigation bar